# mySQL union Returning Table name

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to mash many tables into one query and sorting it by a date.

However I also want a column that defines which table the information came from - this way i can use PHP to decide what to do with the data.

This is what I have so far

```
    SELECT DATABASE() as source, title AS MAIN, id as ID, date 
    FROM collection WHERE userID = '1234' 
    UNION
    SELECT DATABASE() as source, body, id, date 
    FROM blog WHERE posterID = '1234' 
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

Which works well and orders by the date, but the "Source" Column only returns the database
"myusername.dabtabaseName"

Is there anyway mySQL can return the TABLE name which it came from? I had a look around the manual but couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply?

```
    SELECT DATABASE() as source, 'Collection' as TblName,title AS MAIN, id as ID, date 
        FROM collection WHERE userID = '1234' 
        UNION
        SELECT DATABASE() as source, 'Blog' as TblName,body, id, date 
        FROM blog WHERE posterID = '1234' 
        ORDER BY date DESC
```

I doubt any dialect of SQL will provide you a function to indicate the table name of the query, since you can have subqueries, joins, etc.